# How do I use the Windows version of gstreamer and wireshark to take a .pcap file and extract H.264 from RTP?

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, gstreamer, rtp, wireshark

I have a pcap file containing a capture of RTP with H.264 video and SIP with SDP.  I would like to be able to extract the video from the RTP stream and save it to a file. (h264video.mkv or something similar)

I have started looking at gstreamer as a possible solution for this but I'm having trouble troubleshooting any of the output I receive from the program.

```
gst-launch -v     filesrc location=testh264.rtp     
! application/x-rtp,media=video,clock-rate=90000,payload=123,encoding-name=H264     
! rtph264depay                   
! ffdec_h264                     
! xvimagesink
```

Here is an example of something I've tried but I'm not able to get through rtph264depay because the file I'm sending is of invalid format.  What can I do to extract the h264 payload from my pcap file for usage with gstreamer/rtph264depay?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that pcap file does not contain raw RTP payload, it is somehow formatted ([here is how](http://wiki.wireshark.org/Development/LibpcapFileFormat)).
You can extract raw data with [pcapparse plugin](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-bad-plugins/html/gst-plugins-bad-plugins-pcapparse.html):

```
$ gst-launch filesrc location=testh264.rtp
    ! pcapparse
    ! application/x-rtp,media=video,clock-rate=90000,payload=123,encoding-name=H264     
    ! rtph264depay ! ffdec_h264
    ! autovideosink
```

Comment: $ gst-launch ... ... ... ...
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstFileSrc:filesrc0: Internal data flow error.
Additional debug info:
..\..\..\Source\gstreamer\libs\gst\base\gstbasesrc.c(2507): gst_base_src_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstFileSrc:filesrc0:
streaming task paused, reason not-negotiated (-4)
ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...

Comment: It seems that the program doesn't get through the pcapparse portion of the pipeline.  If I remove everything after pcapparse in my pipeline, I still get the exact same error, which seems to point toward pcapparse being the problem.

Comment: Seems that pcapparse can't parse your file. What software you used to create it? Can you upload the file somewhere and post link here?

Comment: I just used wireshark 1.6.1 38096 and saved as .pcap format.  i tried a file containing only udp/rtp packets and also one containing both rtp and sip.  I do not wish to share the capture since it contains confidential information about my University and the network including video of classmates.

Comment: With only udp/rtp packets in file it should be no problem, if there are also sip packets, you need to filter them out by specifying `src-port` property of `pcapparse`.Sorry, don't know what may be the problem if the file is well formed, try asking on gstreamer mailing list.

Answer (score 1):

You should have autovideosink available which will automatically select the correct video sink for you. Otherwise, it is probably something like "dshowsink". Try `gst-inspect` while grepping it for dshow or directshow and it should tell you what to use.

Comment: I just tried autovideosink and I get this error

Received invalid RTP payload, dropping

Comment: @user1118047 Then the problem is either your caps, the actual pipeline, or the problem is in the pcap capture. However, your video sink is not the problem.

Comment: @user1118047 also, put spaces after your commas in your caps.

Comment: At this point I'm very sure that the problem is with the file I'm piping to rtph264depay.  It looks like I need to make sure I'm sending the right information.  The file I'm sending it is a .raw file that wireshark generated when I did a "save as payload" but I have a feeling that file is not the correct format or rtph264depay needs more information...

Comment: Is there a simpler way I should be going about this?  It seems the method I'm trying to use involves extracting the raw h264 payload which will require me stripping the RTP headers by hand with my own code, then sending it to the depayloader, then to the decoder, then to a "sink"  What happens when the stream gets to the sink?  I'd like to be able to save the decoded video to a file, will I be able to do that?

Comment: @user1118047 the depayloader is supposed to handle the rtp headers, not you. If the pcap is giving you the rtp packets in sequence then you shouldn't have to be stripping anything. My guess is that the filesrc is passing the whole thing as a giant blob instead of one rtp packet at a time.

Comment: @user1118047 try setting the blocksize of your filesrc to the mtu of your rtp stream. It is probably 1412

Comment: I tried setting blocksize to my MTU and some other values for good measure, but I still get the same errors.

Answer (score 0):

I see that this post is old but I had the same problem and here is my pipeline that works (using gstreamer-1.0):

```
C:\gstreamer\1.0\x86_64\bin>gst-launch-1.0.exe -m -v filesrc location=C:/Work/log.pcap ! pcapparse src-port=7000 caps="application/x-rtp,media=video,payload=96,clock-rate=90000,encoding-name=H264,profile-level-id=4d0029,sprop-parameter-sets=\"Z00AKeKQFoe2BqwYBBuHiRFQ,aO48gA==\"" ! rtph264depay ! video/x-h264, width=740, height=480, framerate=(fraction)15/1 ! avdec_h264 ! avimux ! filesink location=C:/Work/out.avi
```

The sprop-parameter-sets I got from the SDP file for the camera that sent the rtp stream.